# Adding relationship to the existing node inNeo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cql

I want to add new relationship to the existing node in Neo4j
with this syntax:

```
MATCH (a:User {name: "Jack", surname: "Roe"}),
(b:User {name: "Jack", surname: "Smith"})
CREATE (a) -[r:Knows]-> (b)
RETURN a,r,b
```

but I get this warning : [image]
what does it mean and how should I modify my cypher query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you have nothing to do.

The warning, like it's explained in its description, is that you have a disconnected pattern : `(a:User {name: "Jack", surname: "Roe"})` and `(b:User {name: "Jack", surname: "Smith"})` are not linked.

So to create the result, Neo4j has to compute all the combinations of this 2 sets :

- the one for the node **a**
- the one for the node **b**

So it's a cartesian product between those 2 sets, and it's something that can take a lot of times, specially if one set has a high cardinality.

In your case, I assume you have one node `Roe` and an other `Jack`, so the cartesian product is just  `1 x 1`, so it's easy.

Comment: Thank you . So what is the best way to add relationship to the existing nodes??

Comment: Simply : Like you done (the MATCH, MATCH, CREATE pattern) !

Comment: Unfortunately no changes happen !!! Why it does not make any new changes and why the relationship is not created?